# JavaScript : Create a new array item for every nested item with redundant parent properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am looking to convert a dataset like this

```
[  
   {  
      "suburb":"Collingwood",
      "couples":[  
         {  
            "husband":"Adam",
            "wife":"Brittany"
         },
         {  
            "husband":"Dave",
            "wife":"Carla"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "suburb":"CBD",
      "couples":[  
         {  
            "husband":"Paul",
            "wife":"Christine"
         },
         {  
            "husband":"Mike",
            "wife":"Laura"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

to a dataset like this

```
[  
   {  
      "suburb":"Collingwood",
      "husband":"Adam",
      "wife":"Brittany"
   },
   {  
      "suburb":"Collingwood",
      "husband":"Dave",
      "wife":"Carla"
   },
   {  
      "suburb":"CBD",
      "husband":"Paul",
      "wife":"Christine"
   },
   {  
      "suburb":"CBD",
      "husband":"Mike",
      "wife":"Laura"
   }
]
```

Is there an underscore function to do anything like this or do I need to loop and do it manually. The goal is to display the final list sorted and grouped by wife's name

Comment: Can you please add your attempt at doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one-liner (note that other answers might be more easy to read/maintanable though):

```
const result = [].concat(...input.map(entry => entry.couples.map(couple => ({...{suburb: entry.suburb}, ...couple}))));
```

Demo:

```js
const input = [  
   {  
      "suburb":"Collingwood",
      "couples":[  
         {  
            "husband":"Adam",
            "wife":"Brittany"
         },
         {  
            "husband":"Dave",
            "wife":"Carla"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "suburb":"CBD",
      "couples":[  
         {  
            "husband":"Paul",
            "wife":"Christine"
         },
         {  
            "husband":"Mike",
            "wife":"Laura"
         }
      ]
   }
];

const result = [].concat(...input.map(entry => entry.couples.map(couple => ({...{suburb: entry.suburb}, ...couple}))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your original array to a new array that has the data format you want:

```js
var data = [{
    "suburb": "Collingwood",
    "couples": [{
        "husband": "Adam",
        "wife": "Brittany"
      },
      {
        "husband": "Dave",
        "wife": "Carla"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "suburb": "CBD",
    "couples": [{
        "husband": "Paul",
        "wife": "Christine"
      },
      {
        "husband": "Mike",
        "wife": "Laura"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // expand each couple to a new object and push all results to accumulator array
  acc.push(...curr.couples.map(c => Object.assign({suburb: curr.suburb}, c)));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = oldArray.reduce((result, object) => {
  object.couples.forEach(couple => {
    result.push({
      suburb: object.suburb,
      husband: couple.husband,
      wife: couple.wife
    })  
  })
  return result;
}, []);
```

returns:

```
[ { suburb: 'Collingwood', husband: 'Adam', wife: 'Brittany' },
  { suburb: 'Collingwood', husband: 'Dave', wife: 'Carla' },
  { suburb: 'CBD', husband: 'Paul', wife: 'Christine' },
  { suburb: 'CBD', husband: 'Mike', wife: 'Laura' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested forEach loops to first get the suburb and then get the couples and push all into a new array.

```js
var data =  [{  
  "suburb":"Collingwood",
  "couples":[
    {"husband":"Adam","wife":"Brittany"},
    {"husband":"Dave","wife":"Carla"}
   ]
  }, {  
  "suburb":"CBD",
  "couples":[
    {"husband":"Paul", "wife":"Christine"},
    {"husband":"Mike","wife":"Laura"}
  ]
}]


var newData=[];

data.forEach(function(item){
 var couples = item.couples;

 couples.forEach(function(couple){
  newData.push({
   'suburb': item.suburb,
   'husband': couple.husband,
   'wife': couple.wife
   })
 })
})

console.log(newData)
```